# Проблема с mouseover на DOM img на js

Tags: javascript, img, dom

Помогите разобраться. Создал 3 картинки js'ом. **Задача**: когда я навожу мышкой на картинку, появляется описание в другом DIV'е. Но работает только первая картинка, остальные нет. Как правильно проверить, на какую картинку наведена мышь? Пробовал и через документId, и Name обращаться, но, видимо, как-то не так.

```
    // Воин
var imgW = document.createElement ('img');
    imgW.src = 'img/warrior.png';
    imgW.id = 'imgWarrior';
    imgW.name = 'imgWarrior';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgW.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgW.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgW);
    // Охотник
var imgH = document.createElement ('img');
    imgH.src = 'img/hunter.png';
    imgH.id = 'imgHunter';
    imgH.name = 'imgHunter';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgH);
    // Маг
var imgM = document.createElement ('img');
    imgM.src = 'img/mage.png';
    imgM.id = 'imgMage';
    imgM.name = 'imgMage';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgM.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgM.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgM);

function imgOver () {
    if (imgW) {
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Блядский Воин</strong>.</p>';
    }else if (imgH){
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Охотник за шелупонью</strong>.</p>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Маг подщельник</strong>.</p>';
    };
}
    function imgOut () {
    document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно заменить код

```
imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
```

На

```
imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver("imgWarrior");');
imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut("imgWarrior");');
```

Тем самым сразу сообщать функции, на какой картинке был (есть) фокус.

Функция `over` в свою очередь измениться на нечто вроде

```
function imgOver (hero) {
    switch (hero) {
         case 'imgWarrior':
             document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Блядский Воин</strong>.</p>';
             break
         case 'imgHunter':
             document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Охотник за шелупонью</strong>.</p>';
             break
         case 'imgMage':
             document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Маг подщельник</strong>.</p>';
             break
         default:
             document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Вызов функции без параметров</strong>.</p>';
    }
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться `this`, для этого выражение `if (imgW) {` следует заменить на `if (this.attr("id") == 'imgWarrior') {`, и с последующими условиями так же.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это то, что нужно! this пробовал, но без .attr, и вообще не правильно - теперь понял, что да как.
Еще на stackoverflow подсказали, что вот такую конструкцию можно писать: `imgM.onclick = function(){imgClick()};` - тоже не знал и нигде не видел в учебниках. Вот что получилось: http://jsfiddle.net/kachimov/6cxLa0Lz/7/